# Raspberry Pi and RF module MX-RM-5V power through gpio and noise?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, iot, gpio

i have a tiny RF 433mHz project with my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2 and Arduino Pro mini.

My Raspberry works as a receiver and Pro mini as a transmitter.

I have wiried the popular RF receiver MX-RM-5V to my RPi's GPIO.

Receiver and transmitter modules have coiled antennas.

I used the GPIO 5V pin to supply my receiver and logic level converter.

I'm using logic level converter because the receiver works with 5V and GPIO with 3.3V  logic.

**The problem is that if i use the GPIO 5V pin to supply my RF receiver module  the range drops to 10 cm.**

**When i supply my receiver module with external adapter @ 5V the range increases to 10 - 15 meters.**

Raspberry has micro usb 2A adapter.
The MX-RM-5V uses 11.50 mA.

**Why the GPIO 5V pin can't supply the MX-RM-5V module ?**

Is there some component on the raspberry's 5V rail between micro-usb and gpio 5v pin that limits the current ?

How much noise the Raspberry generates on its rails and what kind ? Can this be the problem ?

Comment: You might get a better answer at [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/); this doesn't seem to be a programming question (see the [help]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

i measured 1kHz constant noise with oscillator from MX-RM-5V module when it is connected to the raspberry pi 3. With external power supply the module works ok. When the module received something the noise dropped to 300-400 Hz.

I found a visual solution and rather simple way from youtube to really see the noise on the data pin.

**THE LED.**

When i connected green LED with a 100 Ohm resistor to the data pin the led is constantly glowing. Its not bright but you see small green light. On this occasion the receiver did not receive nothing. So is was pure constant noise.

Next step was to start messing with **Low pass filter**. I connected 240Ohm resistor and 1.5 uF cap as low pass between data pin and ground. So i connected the greed LED to filtered voltage and the constant noise were filtered.

Led is blinking by the data signals only when the transmitter sends something to the receiver.

Also, my **baudrate** in the transmitter and receiver code was a bit high. I moved from 1000 bits/s down to 200 bits/s.

From now, the raspberry can detect data from this module and everything is a lot better.